# Store Data in MySQL Block

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
 function liveFeed_update() { 
   var symbol_in_table = "SELECT count (*) as total FROM livedata 
     wherescript_name = '"+s_symbol_script+"'";
   con.query(symbol_in_table, function (err, result) {
     if (err) {
       throw err;
     }
     else {
       num_row = + result[0].total;
       console.log("Number of Rows in inner level:",+ num_row);
     }
   });
   console.log("Number of Rows in outer level:",+ num_row);
 }
```

Node.js is executing outer console log first then its going inside. As a result I am not getting proper result.

But I want to execute sql query first and then based on the result I want to proceed further.

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is necessary to ensure any values are properly escaped and won't cause problems. Most drivers have this capability, and those like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) make it easy so there's really no excuse to not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Node.js is *asynchronous* meaning code will run out of order, contrary to your expectations if used to synchronous (blocking) code.

If you need to have `num_row` incremented and returned reliably you'll have to chain this together with one of: a callback, a trailing `then` or use `async`/`await`.

I'd encourage you to use promises:

```
function liveFeed_update() { 
   var symbol_in_table = "...";
   var num_row = 0;

   con.query(symbol_in_table).then(function(results) {
     results.forEach(function(result) {
       num_row = + result[0].total;
       console.log("Number of Rows in inner level:", num_row);
     });
   }).then(function() {
     console.log("Number of Rows in outer level:",+ num_row);
   });
 }
```

The same can be done with callbacks, but then it gets tricky, often depending on the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library.

If you can use `async`/`await` native Node.js features it's even easier, making your async code feel more like conventional synchronous code:

```
async function liveFeed_update() { 
   var symbol_in_table = "...";
   var num_row = 0;

   var results = await con.query(symbol_in_table);

   results.forEach(function(result) {
     num_row = + result[0].total;
     console.log("Number of Rows in inner level:", num_row);
   });

   console.log("Number of Rows in outer level:",+ num_row);
 }
```

Comment: Sir, I tried with second approach, but i am getting following error. "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: results.forEach is not a function"

Comment: This depends on what kind of result `con.query` returns. Normally it's an array of results, but if your driver works differently you may need to adapt it. You didn't specify what you're using in your original code, but if you could explain maybe this could be changed to suit.

Comment: con query will return number of row match to particular string in the following format  [ RowDataPacket { total: 1 } ]

Comment: This code might not work as-is, it serves as a demonstration on how Promise or `async` capable code *can* work. See if your driver supports promises, and if so, how you can use them to simplify your data flow. Remember `function` passed in to something may be run *zero or more times at any point in time between now and the end of your process*.